# ASP.NET Core Integration Test works locally but throws null reference exception when running in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, integration-testing

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages Web App that I have written some integration tests for following [the official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

I can get the tests to run locally using `dotnet test` or the test runners built into Visual Studio. However, on the build server (Azure DevOps Hosted 2017 agent) the tests will return a 500 error. I thought it might be related to user secrets as stated on [Scott Hanselman's guide](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EasierFunctionalAndIntegrationTestingOfASPNETCoreApplications.aspx) but I am still getting the same error, even after implementing some of his suggested fixes (I don't believe I need all of them) :

- Added `builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();` to Startup.
- Implemented a `CustomWebApplicationFactory` to set the environment to "Development" - code below has this as "Production" to reproduce the failure.

I also sanity checked against [this guide](https://fullstackmark.com/post/20/painless-integration-testing-with-aspnet-core-web-api) which is more controller focused but since I only care about the response codes at this stage it serves my purpose. I have downloaded the verbose logs and they don't shed any light on the issue.

My code is below:

CustomWebApplicationFactory:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebPortal.Int.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on https://fullstackmark.com/post/20/painless-integration-testing-with-aspnet-core-web-api
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup> where TStartup : class
    {
        public CustomWebApplicationFactory() { }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ConfigureTestServices(
                    services =>
                    {
                        services.Configure(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, (System.Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>)(o =>
                        {
                            // CookieContainer doesn't allow cookies from other paths
                            o.CorrelationCookie.Path = "/";
                            o.NonceCookie.Path = "/";
                        }));
                    }
                )
                .UseEnvironment("Production")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationTests:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace WebPortal.Int.Tests
{
    public class AuthenticationTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient { get; }

        public AuthenticationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> fixture)
        {
            WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions webAppFactoryClientOptions = new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                // Disallow redirect so that we can check the following: Status code is redirect and redirect url is login url
                // As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#test-a-secure-endpoint
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            };

            _httpClient = fixture.CreateClient(webAppFactoryClientOptions);
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("/")]
        [InlineData("/Index")]
        [InlineData("/Error")]
        public async Task Get_PagesNotRequiringAuthenticationWithoutAuthentication_ReturnsSuccessCode(string url)
        {
            // Act
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            // Assert
            try
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebPortal.Authentication;
using WebPortal.Common.ConfigurationOptions;
using WebPortal.DataAccess;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebPortal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddOptions<PowerBiSettings>()
                .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("PowerBI"))
                .ValidateDataAnnotations()
                .Validate(o => o.AreSettingsValid());

            services.AddOptions<AzureActiveDirectorySettings>()
                .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .ValidateDataAnnotations()
                .Validate(o => o.AreSettingsValid());

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddCookie();

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddTransient<Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler, AuthenticationHandler>();
            services.AddTransient<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Reports");
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27317.07)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.30]   Discovering: WebPortal.Int.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.40]   Discovered:  WebPortal.Int.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.41]   Starting:    WebPortal.Int.Tests
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
    User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
    Creating key {dd820f09-8139-4d7d-954a-399923660f42} with creation date 2019-03-18 22:13:27Z, activation date 2019-03-18 22:13:27Z, and expiration date 2019-06-16 22:13:27Z.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
    Writing data to file 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-dd820f09-8139-4d7d-954a-399923660f42.xml'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
    Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET http://localhost/Index  
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
    Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
    An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
    An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
    Request finished in 449.9633ms 500 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
    Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET http://localhost/Error  
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
    An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]     WebPortal.Int.Tests.AuthenticationTests.Get_PagesNotRequiringAuthenticationWithoutAuthentication_ReturnsSuccessCode(url: "/Index") [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]       System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]       Parameter name: uriString
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.HttpContextBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.Handlers.CookieContainerHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.Handlers.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)[xUnit.net 00:00:02.63]     WebPortal.Int.Tests.AuthenticationTests.Get_PagesNotRequiringAuthenticationWithoutAuthentication_ReturnsSuccessCode(url: "/Error") [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.64]     WebPortal.Int.Tests.AuthenticationTests.Get_PagesNotRequiringAuthenticationWithoutAuthentication_ReturnsSuccessCode(url: "") [FAIL]

[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]            at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]         D:\a\1\s\WebPortal.Int.Tests\AuthenticationTests.cs(24,0): at WebPortal.Int.Tests.AuthenticationTests.Get_PagesNotRequiringAuthenticationWithoutAuthentication_ReturnsSuccessCode(String url)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.61]         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

**edit**

It isn't very clear to me where/why I am getting a null reference because as far as I can tell my `OpenIdConnectOptions` configuration is correct (and it works with AAD SSO).

Comment: Hi, may be stupid question and you have already checked it. But have you tried to move: "builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();" outside of env.IsDevelopment() ?

Comment: Seeing your stracktrace, I'm pretty sure your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719310/3883866)

Comment: @Nikolay yes I have tried this thank you.

Comment: @JessedeWit that suggestion didn't fix it my issue but it did put me onto the fact that my `AzureAd` configuration wasn't being loaded properly during the tests. Hardcoding the values in worked then I realised that I hadn't called `.Build()` on my `ConfigurationBuilder` and assigned the value to the Configuration object. This also meant that I moved the code to include the secrets into the `Startup` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was because I hadn't called `.Build()` on my `ConfigurationBuilder` object that I had created, AND assigned the value to the `Configuration` field inside the `Startup` class. This also meant that I moved the code to include the secrets into the `Startup` constructor.

Even so, my secrets were still not accessible on the build machine (makes sense because they are [stored per machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#how-the-secret-manager-tool-works)). So I had to add a Command Line task to my build pipeline as well - which uses the `dotnet user-secrets set` command to add the secrets in that are required for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you were missing the AzureAd configuration section from you production settings file? i.e. appsettings.json vs appsettings.Development.json